# everytime restart eclipse, source attachment configuration lost

Tags: java, eclipse, attachments

My Eclipse version is 4.6.3, I attach `org.apache.commons.lang.source_xxx.jar` to `org.apache.commons.lang_xxx.jar`, the `org.apache.commons.lang.source_xxx.jar`'s path is same with `org.apache.commons.lang_xxx.jar`. But everytime I restart eclipse, my configuration is lost, I have to reattach it, it's inconvenient.

So I want to know if eclipse can automatically attach source code to its jar? Why My configuration is lost?